# DSE Spark Streaming: Long active batches queue

Tags: cassandra, spark-streaming, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.78")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "20000")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.executor.instances", "3")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "3")
  .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
  .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
  .set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
  .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate", "200")
  .set("spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate", "500")

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "192.168.0.113:9092",
  "group.id" -> "test-group-aditya",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "largest")

val topics = Set("random")
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

I'm running the code through `spark-submit` with the following command:

```
dse> bin/dse spark-submit --class test.kafkatesting /home/aditya/test.jar
```

I have a three-node Cassandra DSE cluster installed on different machines. Whenever I run the application, it takes so much data and starts creating a queue of active batches, which in turn creates a backlog and a long scheduling delay. How can I increase the performance and control the queue such that it receives a new batch only after it finishes executing the current batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, did some optimisation in code. Instead of saving RDD try to create Dataframe, saving DF to Cassandra in much faster as compared to RDD. Also, increase the no of core and and executor memory in order to achieve good results.

Thanks,